# Pagination Not Showing

Tags: pagination

I am showing past events for visitors to reference old performances by using  'show_expired="yes"' however the page got very big so I used pagination to break it up. I also use {if expiration_date < current_date} content {/if}, so only past show are shown.

When I employ pagination, I  get large blank spaces on the first page where the current content wants to show, but I don’t want it too show. How do I disable the pagination from wanting to try and show blank spaces where the current shows are trying to show.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="now_playing"  show_expired="yes"  limit="3" paginate="bottom"}

{if expiration_date < current_time}
 content of paage includes description and photo of past shows
 {/if}

{paginate}
 <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using conditional check inside your channel entries loop, consider providing **stop_before** parameter to limit your entries to those created before certain date. Be aware though the parameter works with entry_date, not expiration_date.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#stop-before

Comment: {exp:channel:entries channel="now_playing" orderby="date" sort="desc"  stop_before="<?php echo $current_time; ?>" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" }

Comment: {exp:channel:entries channel="now_playing" orderby="date" sort="desc"  stop_before="<?php echo $current_time; ?>" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" } does not work.

Comment: Did you use example for the docs or anything else? Is your PHP parsing preference for template set to "On Input", as required?